# INSERT em duas Tabelas com base em SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine o seguinte cenário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em determinado momento é necessário duplicar as pessoas e seus respectivos itens.

Se tenho os seguinte dados:

**Tabela Pessoa**

```
+----+------------+
| Id | Nome       |
+----+------------+
| 1  | Joãozinho  |
| 2  | Mariazinha |
+----+------------+
```

**Tabela PessoaItem**

```
+----+------------+--------+
| Id | PessoaId   | ItemId |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | 1          | 1      |
| 2  | 1          | 2      |
| 3  | 2          | 1      |
+----+------------+--------+
```

**Tabela Item**

```
+----+------------+
| Id | Descricao  |
+----+------------+
| 1  | Item1      |
| 2  | Item2      |
+----+------------+
```

Pode-se concluir com isso que `Joãozinho` possui o `Item1` e `Item2`, e `Mariazinha` possui apenas o `Item1`.

Duplicando os dados, teríamos:

**Tabela Pessoa**

```
+----+------------+
| Id | Nome       |
+----+------------+
| 1  | Joãozinho  |
| 2  | Mariazinha |
| 3  | Joãozinho  |
| 4  | Mariazinha |
+----+------------+
```

**Tabela PessoaItem**

```
+----+------------+--------+
| Id | PessoaId   | ItemId |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | 1          | 1      |
| 2  | 1          | 2      |
| 3  | 2          | 1      |
| 4  | 3          | 1      |
| 5  | 3          | 2      |
| 6  | 4          | 1      |
+----+------------+--------+
```

**Tabela Item**
Permanece como anteriormente.

Para duplicar apenas uma tabela é fácil, basta rodar o seguinte script:

```
INSERT INTO Pessoa
(Nome)
SELECT Nome
FROM Pessoa
```

Mas e neste caso, que envolve mais de uma tabela? Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

> Estou usando SQL Server.

Comment: Você tem de duplicar uma a uma, verificar que os ids são válidos, desabilitar triggers, em alguns casos constraints, etc.

Comment: Acho que o mais apropriado realmente seria criar um laço dentro de uma Transaction e fazer um a um.

Comment: Ok. Mesmo porque, em qualquer dos casos, no frigir dos ovos, será feito de um a um.

Comment: entendo, estou vasculhando a internet, mas não encontro nada que possa me ajudar a criar esse loop para trabalhar um a um dentro dele.

Comment: Vou postar um exemplo.

Comment: Por que você quer desnormalizar teu banco de dados?

Comment: Eu não quero não, mas o cliente tem meu WhatsApp, hahaha...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @campo VARCHAR(30)
    , @campo2 VARCHAR(30)
    , @campo3 VARCHAR(60)

-- Cursor para percorrer os nomes dos objetos 
DECLARE itens CURSOR FOR
    SELECT campo, campo2, campo3 
    FROM
        tabela_origem


-- Abrindo Cursor para leitura
OPEN itens

-- Lendo a próxima linha
FETCH NEXT FROM itens INTO @campo, @campo2, @campo3

-- Percorrendo linhas do cursor (enquanto houverem)
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO TABELA2 VALUES( @campo, @campo2, @campo3 )

    -- Lendo a próxima linha
  FETCH NEXT FROM itens INTO @campo, @campo2, @campo3
END

-- Fechando Cursor para leitura
CLOSE itens

-- Desalocando o cursor
DEALLOCATE itens
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @reginaldo-rigo fiz as adaptações e funcionou perfeito aqui.